# Allow access from one domain with NGINX

Tags: nginx, html5-video, jwplayer, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm looking for a solution to prevent hot-linking with NGINX for JWPlayer. Say I have a NGINX server configured as a reverse proxy at `http://mydomain1.com`, I'll get the url `http://mydomain1.com/file.mp4` to put on my website hosted on another VPS at `http://mydomain2.com`. How do I restrict the file so it can be played on `http://mydomain2.com` only and nowhere else?

I tried `allow & deny` directives but then I realized this is a HTML5 streaming so the directives will block the stream to users.

Comment: So you want browser to say mydomain2.com and then only allow the access?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I want the link I got from domain1 (which is a reverse proxy) to be able to played only on domain2 (two domain on different hosts) using html5 player. Is there any way to configure NGINX for that purpose? I also tried valid_referers directive but it does't work.

Comment: If the servers are different then it will need changes on domain1 nginx and not domain2. You have access to domain1 nginx?

Comment: Yes sure, I have access to both servers, also both of them running on NGINX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the mp4 url will be put in a HTML5 player, this means the remote address (user's machine) will always communicate directly with the reverse proxy. So that's impossible to restrict the access using other methods except nginx secure link module. With this module I'm now able to restrict the access basing on the user's ip, expiration time, url and a secret word.

Answer (score 1):

On nginx of mydomain1.com. Make sure you have one additional block which listens to default host and deny all traffic. Then in the existing listen block we add a rule to allow only `www.mydomain2.com`

```
map $http_referer $not_allowed {
   default 0;
   "~www.mydomain2.com" 1;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    deny all;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.mydomain1.com

   location / {
      if ($not_allowed)
         {
            return 404 "Not sure its there";
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your configuration however it blocked the access of users to mp4 files. I think this is due to the way HTML5 players work. They "stream" the files directly from the reverse proxy with the identity of user's IPs not through domain2, so the server will see it as a unauthorized access. I found an alternative using Nginx http_secure_link_module, trying to implement it.